# Change Android Actionbar subtitle colour

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I wish to customize the actionBar of my android application.
I am using Actionbar Sherlock.
My min target sdk is 14, target sdk 17.
I have a theme that changes the background colour and main title text
however i cannot change the subtitle text colour
my style is shown here

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">#8B0000</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

</style>
```

what have a done wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just change `titleTextStyle` to `subtitleTextStyle`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: That gives the Title style to Subtitle. Subtitle style should be inherited from `@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle`.

Answer (score 3):

This set of styles formats the action bar, including background, title and subtitle text; it also formats the tabs, including all states (selected, unselected, and all the focused/pressed combinations), as well as the tab text font and size (per Android developers instruction https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/themeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabs</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/themeActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabs</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="themeActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abactionbargradient</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarSubTitleText</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/abactionbargradient</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="styleActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="styleActionBarSubTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_sub_title_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="styleActionBarTabText"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="styleActionBarTabs"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abactionbartabs</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/abactionbartabs</item>
</style>
```

This set of styles looks especially nice when the drawables are gradients using some set of coherent color values (i.e. lavender to purple for selected and purple to lavender for unselected, changing the values to darker for pressed and lighter for focused).

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your activity file

```
 actionBar.setSubtitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFBF00'>Here ActionBar Subtitle</font>"));
```

Comment: it's bad coding

Answer (score 2):

Almost there. Here is the code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="android:background">#8B0000</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In case you get an API level 13 warning - just use (for both TitleTextStyle, and Subtitle) @android/style/TextApperance for the parent.

Answer (score 1):

example add

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
```

subtitleColor

```
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this (Its closer to what i need)


    
        `@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar
        @style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar`

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="android:background">#8B0000</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step:

1) Include actionbar by id

2) Check if action bar exist (not null)

3) Check apk version

4) Change text color and background color of subtitle

```
Toolbar actionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar); //change R.id.action_bar with your action bar id

       if (actionBarToolbar != null) // check if action bar is not null

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // check version of apk

         actionBarToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)); // change actionBarToolbar background color

         actionBarToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE); // finally  this line change subtitle text color

        }
```