# Changing color of tab text without affecting title

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am using the action bar to have three tabs. The action bar also has a title and a subtitle. Most of the questions on SO are about changing the color of the actionbar itself. But currently the title and subtitle are of the right color but the text of the tabs are not. How do I change the text color of the tab text without affecting the title and subtitle??

Comment: post your code and tell that what you have tried ??

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477617/change-android-actionbar-subtitle-colour

Comment: Ive tried changing it from the styles.xml, but that changes the title and subtitle color. Ive also tried using html.fromHtml and sending in the hexcode.

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya that question is for changing the subtitle color. i dont want to change the subtitle color.